# overlay background images not showing up

Tags: css, z-index, background-image, rounded-corners

I'm trying to create rounded images (fixed width in this situation, so I just want to use an overlay png) but the corner overlay does not seem to be showing up.

The mark-up looks like this:

```
 <div class="rounded roundTop">
     <div class="rounded roundBottom">
         <img />
     </div> 
 </div>



.rounded {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}

.roundTop{    
    background: transparent url('../@gui/round-img-top-155.png') top left no-repeat; 
}

.roundBottom{
    background: transparent url('../@gui/round-img-bottom-155.png') bottom left no-repeat;   
}

img {  
    width: 155px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
```

The .rounded divs appear to be in the right place, but their backgrounds aren't showing up and I'm not sure as to why!

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ch5w8/)

I try assigning a solid background color to the container divs and they go under the image despite their z-index.

I can get the borders in front of the image by sending the image itself to the back, but then it gets covered by all the other elements in the page.

Comment: What is the empty img tag for? As far as i can see they are where they need to be. Only problem might be that you have nothing specified for the <img /> which leaves it empty and probably 0px height. Edit: Maybe also those @gui path? never seen a path with an @ sign.

Comment: Do you have a live link?

Comment: I just took the img src out because it was a relative path and I do not have the project online currently..

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `z-index` from the container elements and just set a negative `z-index` on the image, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ch5w8/4/).

Comment: still not totally clear on why that's necessary.. shouldn't it not matter what contains what if the z-index is specifically set? (I guess clearly it does tho..)

Comment: so as it is I can't position the container elements on top of the img, I have to position the containers beneath the image? and then position every other containing element (wrapper, content, post etc) behind that?  there has to be a better way!

Comment: @Damon, no you have to position the image below the containers using a negative z-index for the image and no z-index at all for the containers. Just look at the example at jsfiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ch5w8/5/ .. the image is behind its container (not the direct containers, but other elements on the page)

Answer (score 0):

I assume they're not showing up at all? I'd venture to guess it's because of your url. I don't think "@" is a valid character to use in file names (if it is, it's not really good practice).

A good way to check to make sure the browser is finding the file is to open up the browser's developer tools (for Firefox, you'll need to install Firebug; the others are built in), and look at the CSS view. You should be able to click on or hover over the URL and see if it loads a preview (I know that works in Firebug, I think it works in the others, if not, you should be able to tell by whether it's downloaded the file in the download view).

Beyond that, a live link or a jsfiddle would help.

Comment: the image links are coming up.  The @ symbols were weird to me as well, but they're part of the CMS I have to use.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix it:

```
.roundBottom{
    padding: 18px 0px;
    background: transparent url('http://ctrlshiftweb.com/round-img-bottom-155.png') bottom left no-repeat;
}
```

You need to take into account the height of the image. :D

Comment: this doesn't address the overlays being behind the images. it does help them line-up properly.. but i am confused why it is an issue. I want the image to be the same size as its container div.. why should padding be necessary?

Comment: Are you serious? You're placing an **opaque** image on a div. Of course you're not going to see the "corners" cause it's a background-image. If you want it to work as you've coded it, make your jpg image into a png with transparency.

Comment: Your code with the image changed (png with transparency): http://jsfiddle.net/ynzRp/

Comment: @kei.. the jpg is supposed to go on the bottom and have no need for transparency, with the corner pic going on top of it to give the appearance of rounded corners (background div color would match the color of the png)